# how to pass multiple values to code behind from webapi url?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to pass multiple values from the url using `WebApi`, but getting some errors.

Currently, I can pass a single value using the code below:

```
[HttpGet]
public String PostAction([FromUri] string name)
{
    return "Post Action";
}
```

How can I achieve it? I need the url format also, any help is appreciated

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: what about pass the value as an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With WebAPI, when you use `FromUri` that means it is coming from the query string.  Adding another `FromUri` argument to your function marked with `HttpGet`will read another parameter of that name from the query string. So if you make a request to `http://localhost/mycontroller/myaction?myFirstParam=firstParamValue&mySecondPar=secondParamValue`, that will map the matching query string values to the parameters of your endpoint.

```
public String MyAction([FromUri] string myFirstParam, [FromUri] string mySecondParam)
```